# Show toolbar icon only when item is long clicked in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, icons, toolbar

I have a Listview in my layout that lists the files in a directory and I intend to show a delete icon on my action bar when one of the items in the Listview is long selected...I have tried going through some posts in this forum but could not find one that explains how to achieve that..
Here is the class file that controls the behavior of the layout file...

```
class Notes: AppCompatActivity{
    // Listview declaration
      ListView noteslist;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     //Listview definition
          noteslist = this.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.noteslist);
          noteslist.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, myfile.ListFiles());
        //list item long selection event handler
        noteslist.ItemLongClick += (s, e) =>
                {
                    
                    //Setbackground for selected item
                    for(int i = 0; i < noteslist.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (e.Position == i)
                        {
                  /*Code to show delete icon on Action bar
                         I tried to override with OnCreateOptionsMenu but it populates the toobar 
                 when OnCreate is called and that is not what i intend to achieve.
                         I want that section of the toolbar to be empty when OnCreate is called and 
       only populate icon when an item on this listis long selected 
                         */
                        }else{
                        
                        }
     }

}
```

Comment: You can use ActionModeCallback to do this.

Comment: Can you post code on how i can use that to achieve what i need?

Comment: Set a bounty and I will be right on your question with an Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About contextual action bar for listview item deletion using action bar, I do one sample that you can take a look:

Layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<ListView android:id="@+id/List"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public List<string> items;
   public ListView listView;
    public ActionMode mActionMode;
    public MyAdapter myAdapter;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        items = new List<string> { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" };
        listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, items);
        listView.Adapter = myAdapter;

        listView.ItemLongClick += ListView_ItemLongClick; 
        listView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
    }

    private void ListView_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        OnListItemSelect(e.Position);
    }

    private void OnListItemSelect(int position)
    {
        myAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
        bool hasCheckedItems = myAdapter.getSelectedCount() > 0;

        if (hasCheckedItems && mActionMode == null)
            mActionMode = StartActionMode(new ActionModeCallback(this));
        else if (!hasCheckedItems && mActionMode != null)
            mActionMode.Finish();

        if (mActionMode != null)
            mActionMode.Title = (myAdapter.getSelectedCount().ToString() + "selected");
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

ActionModeCallBack.cs:

```
   public class ActionModeCallback : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{
    MainActivity parent;

    public ActionModeCallback(MainActivity parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        //wewillcallcab_menu.xmlforsetthe menu
        //wewillcreatecab_menu.xml later
        mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            //ifuserclickmenu print_me
            case Resource.Id.action_delete:
                //createanalert dialog
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(parent);
                string msg = "Are you sure you want to delete items?";
                builder.SetMessage(msg)
                  .SetCancelable(false)
                  .SetPositiveButton("Yes", (or, er) => {

                      SparseBooleanArray selected = parent.myAdapter.getSelectedIds();
                      List<string> list_item = new List<string>();
                      for (int i = (selected.Size() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
                      {
                          //checkisvaluecheckedby user
                          if (selected.ValueAt(i))
                          {
                              string selectedItem = (string)parent.myAdapter.GetItem(selected.KeyAt(i));
                              parent.items.Remove(selectedItem);
                              list_item.Add(selectedItem.ToString());
                          }
                      }
                      //print message
                      Toast.MakeText(parent, "YouSelect" + parent.myAdapter.getSelectedCount() + "Item:[" + string.Join(",", list_item) + "]", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                      mode.Finish();

                  })
                .SetNegativeButton("No", (or, er) => {
                    ((Dialog)or).Cancel();
                });

                Android.App.AlertDialog alert = builder.Create();
                alert.Show();

                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        parent.myAdapter.removeSelection();
        parent.mActionMode = null;
    }
}
```

MyAdapter inhert BaseAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    List<string> items;
    Activity context;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<string> items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }
    
    public override string this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (view == null || holder == null)
        { // otherwise create a new one
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.my_label = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
            view.Tag = (holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;
        }
        holder.my_label.TextSize = 30;//set textSize
        holder.my_label.Text = items[position];//setdata label
                                               //view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position];

        if (mSelectedItemsIds.Size() > 0)
        {
            holder.my_label.SetTextColor(context.LayoutInflater.Context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.grey));
        }

        //checkifcurrentitemhavebeen checked
        //ifyes,changetextcolorwith green
        if (mSelectedItemsIds.Get(position))
        {
            holder.my_label.SetTextColor(context.LayoutInflater.Context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.green));
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int position)
    {
        selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.Get(position));
    }

    public void removeSelection()
    {
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void selectView(int position, bool value)
    {
        if (value)
            mSelectedItemsIds.Put(position, value);
        else
            mSelectedItemsIds.Delete(position);

        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedCount()
    {
        return mSelectedItemsIds.Size();
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds()
    {
        return mSelectedItemsIds;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView my_label;
}
```

Create Menu folder in resource folder, then create menu.xml.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
     android:showAsAction="always"
     android:text="Delete"
     android:icon="@drawable/check"/>

 </menu>
```

If you have any problem, please take a look this sample at github:

https://github.com/CherryBu/ListViewdemo

The screenshot:

[image]